# Riemann integral of two same functions except at finitely many points.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, riemann-integration

Here is my proof.

Theorem: If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b],c\in[a,b]$, and $g(x)=f(x)$ except for finitely many points $c_1,\cdots,c_k$ in $[a,b]$, then $g$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, and $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx.$

Suppose another function $g$ such that $g(x)=f(x)$ except for finitely many points $c_1,\cdots,c_k$. Since $f$ is Riemann integrable, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{4n\sum_{i=1}^{k}|g(c_i)-f(c_i)|}$ such that for any partition $P=(a=x_0,\cdots,x_n=b)$ with $\left\lVert P\right\rVert<\delta$, we have $\left|R(f,P)-\int_{a}^{b}f\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$ Now, 
\begin{align*}
\left|R(g,P)-\int_{a}^{b}f\right|&=\left|R(g,P)-R(f,P)+R(f,P)-\int_{a}^{b}f\right|\\
&\leq\left|R(g,P)-R(f,P)\right|+\left|R(f,P)-\int_{a}^{b}f\right|\\
&<\left|R(g,P)-R(f,P)\right|+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\\
&<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon.\\
\end{align*}where \begin{align*}
|R(g,P)-R(f,P)|&=\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}g(x_i*)(x_i-x_{i-1})-\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_i*)(x_i-x_{i-1})\right|\\
&=\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}(g(x_i^*)-f(x_i^*))(x_i-x_{i-1})\right|\\
&<\sum_{i=1}^{k}|g(c_i)-f(c_i)|(2n\delta)\\
&=2n\sum_{i=1}^{k}|g(c_i)-f(c_i)|\left(\frac{\epsilon}{4n\sum_{i=1}^{k}|g(c_i)-f(c_i)|}\right)\\
&<\frac{\epsilon}{2}
\end{align*}

Is my proof of this theorem correct?

Comment: I see one technical issue, you've selected $\delta$ only to tailor to the needs of $|R(g,P)-R(f,P)|<\epsilon/2$ but actually you need $\delta$ small enough for both that and for $|R(f,P)-I(f)|<\epsilon/2$. Thus you need to choose $\delta_1,\delta_2$ for both those requirements and then take the minimum of the two $\delta$'s. Additionally, $\delta$ shouldn't directly depend on the number of points in the partition, i.e. $n$. (It will depend on the number of points where $g \neq f$, i.e. $k$.)

Comment: I get your first point. But for the second point, the reason i put $n$ inside $\delta$ because there is cases (maximally) that the points lies in two subintervals. (So $n$ points correspond to maximally 2n subintervals,) If i didn't put $n$ in $\delta$, I can't cancel off the $n$

Comment: You can avoid that problem more easily by scaling everything against the maximum of $|g(c_i)-f(c_i)|$ rather than the sum. Then it doesn't matter if two of the $c_i$ are somehow so close together that two of them are in the same subinterval, because that subinterval still contributes at most $\frac{\epsilon}{2k}$ to the sum over "bad" subintervals. There might then be fewer than $k$ "bad" subintervals, but that's not a problem. The way you did it now is actually circular, because actually you should be given $\delta$ and then $n$ is determined from the partition itself.

Comment: To avoid the clutter, assume wlog that $f$ and $g$ differ at only one point, $c$ Then, for a given partition $P$ wlog $c\in P$ and arrange it so that $x_i<c<x_{i+2}$ satisfies $x_{i+2}-x_i<\epsilon$, and the proof will fall out.

Comment: @Matematleta You can't make assumptions like "wlog $c \in P$" without invoking the equivalence of Riemann and Darboux integration. Without that, the only thing you can do is limit the mesh size $\| P \|$. (Now to be sure, invoking the equivalence of Riemann and Darboux integration is a perfectly good way to do this problem.)

Comment: @Ian Fair enough. The equivalence is a straightforward calculation. And worth doing IMO. In any case, one can certainly still assume $f$ and $g$ differ at only one point.

Comment: Let us see if f differs from g by only one point. Then that point has the possibility that this point lies at $x_i$ in the subintervals $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ and $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$. Then when doing the Riemann sum , I have to do it for two subintervals. This is my idea when it is one point. Then , for finitely many points, now i have $k$ points for which these $k$ points have the possibility to lie in $2k$ subinterval. (one point 2 subintervals).

Comment: The point is that the restriction involving $\delta$ should just be $\| P \|<\delta$ for some number, but your form also requires the partition to be a particular size, which isn't how the definitions work. But I think really the problem is in your actual calculation: you should've gotten the bound $|R(g,P)-R(f,P)| \leq \sum_{i=1}^k |g(c_i)-f(c_i)| \delta$, so you need $\delta<\frac{\epsilon}{\sum_{i=1}^k |g(c_i)-f(c_i)|}$, and that's all. Note that this might have multiple $c_i$ in the same subinterval, but that just makes the bound less tight, not false.

Comment: By splitting the interval $[a, b] $ into a finite number of subintervals such that each $c_i$ is an end point of one subinterval we can reduce the problem to case where $k=1$ and $c_1$ is an end point $a$ or $b$. Now the proof is far simpler to type/write.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh the statement you said is actually part (a) of this question . What I am stuck is how to generalise it to finitely many points . Is there anyway I can write to generalise it after I proved Part (a)?

Comment: Read my previous comment. You have to split the interval $[a, b] $ using the points $c_i$. As an example for $k=2$ split like $[a, c_1],[c_1,d],[d,c_2],[c_2,b]$ and $a<c_1<d<c_2<b$. Now each subinterval has only one troublesome point $c_i$ and that is an end point of the subinterval.

Comment: The problem is now c_1 is contained in two subintervals , which are [a,c_1] and [c_1,d]. When you do the sum, you need to do two times , one at the first subinterval , one at another subintervals . ( That's why we have maximally <2(g(c)-f(c))/delta

Answer (score 5):

Your approach via Riemann sums can be simplified with lesser use of symbolism. Let $M$ be a positive upper bound for both $|f|, |g|$ on $[a, b] $. Since $f$ is integrable, say with integral $I$, then for every $\epsilon>0$ we have a $\delta'>0$ such that for any partition $P$ of $[a, b] $ with norm $||P||<\delta'$ we have $$|S(f, P) - I|<\frac{\epsilon} {2}$$ where $$P=\{x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$$ and $$S(f, P) =\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(t_i)(x_i-x_{i-1}),\, t_i\in[x_{i-1},x_i]$$ Since $g(x) =f(x) $ except for a finite number $k$ of exceptional points we have $$|S(g, P) - S(f, P) |<2Mk||P||$$ and thus if we choose $\delta$ such that $0<\delta <\min(\delta',\epsilon/(4Mk))$ we have $$|S(g, P) - S(f, P) |<\frac{\epsilon} {2}$$ whenever $||P||<\delta$ and thus $$|S(g, P) - I|<\epsilon$$ whenever $||P||<\delta$. This means that $g$ is also Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $ with the same integral $I$.

In short, *changing the values of a function at a finite number of points affects neither its Riemann integrability nor the value of its integral (if it exists)*.

The word *finite* in above statement can't be replaced by *infinite*.

Comment: Do you mean $M$ is maximum of $f(c_i)-g(c_i)$ ?

Comment: @LingMinHao: Well $M$ is a positive upper bound for both $|f|, |g|$ and hence $|f(c) - g(c) |\leq 2M$