# Problems regarding certain approaches to some certain integrands

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

While solving some problems of integration(indefinite) I came across some integrands which becomes a lot easier to integrate  if numerator and denominator is multiplied by certain expressions. But what are the consequences to it? 3 examples(almost the same issue) are shown below:

**Example-1:** $$\int{\frac1 {1+\sin x} dx}$$

In this function if we multiply both numerator and denominator with $(1-\sin x)$, then it becomes lot easier to determine the integral. Here the initial function was defined at $x=\frac\pi 2$ but when we are transforming the function to $\frac{1-\sin x} {1-\sin^2 x}$ we are basically multiplying the numerator and denominator by $\frac0 0$ at $x=(4n+1)\frac\pi 2$. Moreover the new function is itself undefined at  $x=(2n+1)\frac\pi 2$. So we have changed the domain of the function by transforming it. What are the consequences to such integrands? Considering this as an indefinite integration, isn't it completely wrong to solve this integral since we dont know the limits even though they represent the same graph but undefined at some more points than it used to?

Again if we transform the function from the expression of $\sin x$ to an expression of $\tan\frac x 2$ isn't it still wrong since at $x=\pi$ the expression becomes undefined?

**Example-2:**$$\int{\frac{(x^2+1)} {(x^4+1)} dx}$$

I was taught to solve this type of integrals by taking  $x^2$ outside the parentheses as common. But isn't it wrong since we are just dividing the expression inside the parentheses by $x^2$ which could also equal $0$? The new function(transformed) is undefined at $x=0$ whereas for any real value of $x$ the initial function is defined.

Another question: is $f(x)=x^2-1=x(x-1)$ for all real values of $x$? I am asking this question because when we do take any term common or take it outside the parentheses, we usually divide the expression inside the parentheses with that term as I have mentioned above.

**Example-3:**$$\int{\frac1 {1+3\cos^2 x} dx}$$
Here if we replace with $\cos x$ with $\frac1 {\sec x}$ , will it be a right thing to do since we are again restricting the domain to a lesser number of possible values as the previous 2?

I am facing almost the same problem regarding all the 3 examples shown above. I know that all the transformed functions are graphically the same as their initial counterparts and if these were definite integrals having limits which don't include those points at which the transformed ones are undefined, then they would  yield the same integral. But what if the limits include those points?(Again I am asking this question because I am considering that since the initial functions are defined at those points then there might be a function which has the same slope coinciding with the initial function at those points) Moreover these are indefinite integrals. It is to be noted that I were taught to solve integral in such ways at my school....there might be many other ways to do so but till now I am unaware of those. I just want to know whether this processes are legitimate or not and would yield the same output or no and what are their consequences.

Comment: This may also give guidance: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4221576/why-and-how-do-certain-manipulations-in-indefinite-integrations-just-work/4221614#4221614

Answer (score 2):

> What are the consequences to such integrands? Considering this as an indefinite integration, isn't it completely wrong to solve this integral since we dont know the limits even though they represent the same graph but undefined at some more points than it used to?

If two integrands disagree only at finitely many points then the integral is the same. [Refer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3127559/riemann-integral-of-two-same-functions-except-at-finitely-many-points), [2](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-prove-that-if-two-functions-differ-at-a-finite-number-of-points-then-their-lower-Riemann-integrals-are-equal), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3523634/two-functions-differing-at-finitely-many-points-have-the-same-riemann-integral) also a function with finitely many discontinuities in an interval is also integrable [refer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102844/how-do-i-prove-that-a-function-with-a-finite-number-of-discontinuities-is-rieman)

P.S: All the trig integral can be solved easily using exponential substitution and the rational function by considering partial fractions on the denominator $x^4 + 1 = (x^2 + i) (x^2 -i)$ .

Comment: Well I am considering only real functions so......

Comment: You may then be in something called Risch algorithim , it is a computer program to solve any integrable integral @MSKB

Comment: Aren't all those tricks wrong since I am just restricting the functions by changing their forms?

Comment: Have a look again, if the number of discontinuity is finite, it is not a problem @MSKB

Comment: lets say if the limit of the third example(definite integral) is $[0,\pi]$  isn't considering $\cos x = \frac {1 (\sec x)}$ wrong? I am implying it wrong because secant of $\pi/2$ is supposed to be undefined.

Comment: Here sec x explodes out to infinity, hence the integral isn't well defined. Even if the function is discontinous at a point, we need to be bounded for it to be integrable Have a look at the links provided.

Comment: I'm quite unfamiliar with the Reimann Integrability

Comment: It is the rigorous definition of an integral

Comment: But in the first example, there are countably infinitely many points at which the function is not defined. I think you mean that a function with countably infinitely many problematic values or less will still have the same integral.

Comment: If you consider the interval as the whole real set, then I don't think the integral realy converges to a value @ArjunVyavaharkar, so you would only take a subset and in that it would be finite

Comment: @Buraian The set of real numbers is uncountably infinite. I'm talking about countable infinity. For example, the natural numbers, $\mathbb{N}$, is really just a subset of the real numbers, $\mathbb{R}$. The set of rational numbers has the same cardinality as the set of natural numbers, which is $\aleph_0$. Even the set of all algebraic numbers has a cardinality of $\aleph_0$. Hell, even the set of all COMPUTABLE numbers has a cardinality of $\aleph_0$.

Comment: If the set of all problematic points has a cardinality of only $\aleph_0$ or less, then the integral still converges on the interval. Do you understand? If a function $f$ is defined such that $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then it doesn't matter if it has countably many exceptions. The number of real numbers completely dwarfs the set of all natural numbers because the cardinality of the real number set is equal to the cardinality of the power set of the natural numbers, which is $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: could you give a source for the claim that it will converge if it is countably infinite so I can add that into my answer and complete it @ArjunVyavaharkar

Comment: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125b/ch1.pdf

Comment: @ArjunVyavaharkar: Nice try. But your musings about infinite cardinalities have absolutely nothing to do with (Riemann) integration. And BTW that the cardinality of the real number set would be $2^{\aleph_0}$ is hitherto unproven.

Comment: I don't think you know how to read, because, in my comments, I said explicitly that a function with countably many discontinuities is still integrable. Also, the cardinality of any set with a cardinality of $n$ has a power set with a cardinality of $2^n$. The set of all real numbers is bijective with the power set of all natural numbers, and since the set of all natural numbers has a cardinality of $\aleph_0$ BY DEFINITION, the power set of the natural numbers must have a cardinality of $2^{\aleph_0}$. This has been more rigorously proven elsewhere.

Comment: What you're talking about is the continuum hypothesis, which has absolutely nothing to do with this discussion. It asserts that the cardinality of the real numbers, $2^{\aleph_0}$, is equal to the cardinality of the first uncountable set, $\aleph_1$. That is to say that there are no cardinalities between $\aleph_0$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$, which is *undecidable*.